What is the correct way to read files off a modern android phone on windows 10/11
I've tried searching, but not had much luck, most answers are a decade old or cryptically mention 'MTP' which yields little in the way of windows APIs for interacting with MTP devices.
Are there even standard microsoft APIs for windows for reading files off of android phones?
Happy to use C++ or C#

A search on windows mtp client site:github.com on a major search engine turns up projects like this and this, which may give you some leads.
